# Customizing one route in Rails 3 resources function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

By default the resources command generates the url for `new` action as `{model}/new`. Sending a `path_names = {}` hash doesn't change the base `{model}` according to the documentation. How would I go about routing `/submit` to `posts#new` action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
match 'submit' => 'posts#new'
```

I hope this is what you are looking for...

You might want to have a look at those two awesome screencasts by Ryan Bates if you wish to understand how it works behind the scene.

[routing-walkthrough](http://railscasts.com/episodes/231-routing-walkthrough) [routing-walkthrough-part-2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/232-routing-walkthrough-part-2)